# JQuery validate div contents

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am trying to click a save button and then call the validate function on my div section where all the fields that need validation have the required tag.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function() {
                $('#MyDIv').valid();
            });
        });

    </script>

<div id="MyDIv">
  <input type="text" class="required" id="id1" />
  <input type="text" id="id2" />
  <input type="button" id="button" />
</div>
```

With this code I am getting a validator is undefined error. I cannot use a form.

Comment: I am using the jquery validate package

Comment: Yes, but why can't you use a form element? jQuery validate is meant to validate forms... Do you just not want the form to submit?

Comment: I am using knockout js and have so far be unable to have any of the desired functionality mixing the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/3BKcp/2/

Wrap a `<form>` tag around your form fields like so:

```
<div id="MyDIv">
     <form method="post" action="/next-page.html">
        <input type="text" class="required" name="id1" id="id1" />
        <input type="text" class="required" name="id2" id="id2" />
        <input type="button" id="button" />
     </form>
</div>
```

and change your JavaScript to the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#MyDIv form').validate();
    $("#button").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If I do what you say I don't get the error but it doesn't display the validation method which is desired.

Comment: This only works if I only have one field that is required. If I have two it displays one error message if it is invalid and then I correct it and then press the button, the page will submit.

Comment: Make sure each field contains a unique `name` property. Updated my answer and demo link.

Comment: EDIT to fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/F787v/ use the submit button to enable you to eliminate some js code

Answer (score 0):

you haven't called `validate()` and you are not using form so it wont work

`validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method

you can  do this like below with only jquery

```
  var required =$(".required").val()
 if((/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(name)) && reqiired.length >6 ){}
```

if required is text and you want only letters not number

if its

1. username than try `/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/`
2. password than `/^[a-z0-9_-]{6,18}$/`
3. email than `/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/`
4. url than     `/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/`